# Most efficient way of searching and adding to a large list that grows with every loop

Tags: python, performance

In short, I have a list (coordinates) inside a list (other info relating to the point) inside a list (list of all the points). It needs to be able to handle tens of thousands of values, and obviously will slow down exponentially, so ideally the most efficient solution would be useful.

For each time the code runs, it will add a new item to the list, so sorting isn't an option.
I've seen people suggest sets, but would that work in this case where the list grows and the value I need is inside the main values? Alternatively I can think of using a separate set storing just the coordinates as a set, but would the increased memory requirement be worth the extra speed?

The way I currently do it is similar to this:

```
growingList = [ [[1,0,0],0,0], [[1,1,0],1,0] ]
itemToAdd = [5,7,3]

itemExists = False
for i in range( len(growingList) ):
    if itemToAdd == growingList[i][0]:
        itemExists = True
        break
if itemExists == False:
    growingList.append( [itemToAdd, otherValue, otherValue2] )
```

Comment: Time/space trade offs are quite common. If you want more speed, consider using more space.

Comment: Would a separate set be the best bet in this case then?

Comment: If a separate set solves your problem and you're happy with speed/memory performance afterwards then I'd say that's a good solution.

Comment: Probable answer: use a set for fast lookup. You will need to change your elements to tuples, though -- set elements need to be immutable. Also, the formatting of `growingList` is wrong. It generates a syntax error.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I'll end up using a separate set for speed. When you say tuples, do you mean I must enter the coordinates into the set as (x,y,z), and not a list, for it to efficiently work?

Comment: Hmm, you could use something like sqlite + spatialite for this kind of stuff (see https://github.com/lokkju/pyspatialite ), might be a good idea if you really have 10.000s of points to track.

Comment: Please avoid asking more than one question in a single "post". Your title doesn't contain any reference to coordinates or looking up nearest neighbours so you should either remove all references to that part of the question and ask a new question about nearest neighbours (but search before asking!) or you should rephrase your question ( including title) to make it a single question about dynamic spatial datasets and efficient nearest neighbours (in which case the part about growing list is a bit irrelevant, except as an example).

Comment: As I'm using the code within maya, I'm unfortunately limited to the default language (if I was to submit it anywhere, it'd need to work straight away), but cheers for the suggestion anyway ;p   And fair enough, I've removed the other question from the original post, I'll worry about it later once I get the main part fully functional (unless of course I'd need to entirely change my method for the nearest neighbours part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a set of unique items, and associated data. The data structure you are looking for is a dictionary. Here is code equivalent to your example using a dictionary:

```
data = { (1, 0, 0): [0, 0], (1, 1, 0): [1, 0] }
keytoadd = (5, 7, 3)
valuetoadd = [othervalue, othervalue2]

if keytoadd not in data:
    data[keytoadd] = valuetoadd
```

It definitely does not slow down exponentially as you worried. Average case insert is constant time (O(1)). If you need a list, then you can get that easily when you need it from the dictionary: `data.items()`.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, I'll try this, I wasn't aware dictionaries didn't slow down with size, would this method be better than storing a separate set of coordinates then?

Comment: Dicts and sets are basically the same performance. But with sets you only have keys, and cannot associate values. As you have values associated with the keys (coordinates), a dictionary is the natural data structure. So you definitely want the dictionary.